# Take Panoramic photo in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic 3.4.0 and am able to take a single photo with it being saved to the library on iOS. I would like to take Pano photos on iOS. How can I do that?

Comment: Tried using @ionic-native/media-capture but no luck. I only get the option to switch from photo to video. I would like to the options of having Video, Photo and Pano in iOS and ideally items such as HDR and photo filter.